# issue with HTML5 boilerplate and safai/chrome/ any other browser

Tags: css, html, frontend, html5boilerplate

I am developing a website with HTML5 Boilerplate and when started checking it on iPhone saw that it doesn't look good at all. It looks like body gets one width (320px) and other elements get another larger than body causing the webpage look like this

screenshot from chrome https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzdd04wufckcewr/Screenshot%202014-01-20%2008.20.51.png

screenshot iOS simulator https://www.dropbox.com/s/llj4w0gp1cxsh86/Screenshot%202014-01-20%2008.21.21.png

I am using normalize.css default styles. The  site has some mixed width for example one div's have a 940px width others should have 100% of viewport.

Has anyone seem this problem before? How can it be fixed? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please Give me your web site code

Comment: Yes; without seeing the source we can't do much. Give us a link to your site, post the relevant HTML+CSS here, or, preferably, make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem.